# Arduino send GET request to server on local network

Tags: http, arduino, raspberry-pi, lan

I have a local network composed of 2 devices:

1. Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with an Apache server. (IP 169.254.90.117)
2. Arduino MEGA with an Arduino Ethernet Shield. (IP 169.254.90.110)

The 2 devices are directly connected via Ethernet cable.

What I want to do is pretty straight forward: be able to send a GET request from the Arduino to the server hosted on the Raspberry Pi in order to modify records on a database.
Unfortunately every time I try Arduino fails to connect to the server and the serial console shows this:

```
Initialising...
Trying to connect to server
connection failed
```

I know that the Raspberry server is working because I tried connecting the Raspberry to a PC from which I was able to navigate with a browser to the website hosted on the server without any issues.

I also tried pinging the Arduino from the Raspberry and the ping is successful.

After navigating through a few forums I tried changing the variable type on the Arduino where I saved the server's IP from a normal `char` variable to a `byte` and a `IPAddress` but with no success.

Here's the Arduino code I've been using:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 169, 254, 90, 110 }; 

char server[] = "169.254.90.117";
//byte server[] = { 169, 254, 90, 117 };
//IPAddress server(169,254,90,117); 

String HTTP_METHOD = "GET";
String PATH_NAME   = "/setNumber.php";
String queryString = "?test=26";

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  Serial.println("Initialising...");
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  
  // connect to web server on port 80:
  Serial.println("Trying to connect to server");
  if(client.connect(server, 80)>0) {
    // if connected:
    Serial.println("Connected to server");
    
    // make a HTTP request:
    // send HTTP header
    client.println(HTTP_METHOD + " " + PATH_NAME + queryString + " HTTP/1.1");
    Serial.println("Sending GET: " + HTTP_METHOD + " " + PATH_NAME + queryString + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + String(server));
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println(); // end HTTP header

    while(client.connected()) {
      if(client.available()){
        // read an incoming byte from the server and print it to serial monitor:
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.print(c);
      }
    }

    // the server's disconnected, stop the client:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnected");
  } else {// if not connected:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

**EDIT:**

I've updated the `char` variable to a `char[]` array but the result is still the same.

To verify that the Arduino Ethernet Shield was working properly I connected it to the internet and succesfully sent a request to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com).

Comment: `char server` means a single character, do you means `char server[] ="169.254.90.117"`? Don't you see it on the Serial Monitor of what's went wrong?  Instead of doing something like `HTTP_METHOD + " " + PATH_NAME + queryString + " HTTP/1.1"`, it will be better to just do `"GET /setNumber.php?test=26 HTTP/1.1"`, it make less mistake like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the workaround I ended up using:

```cpp
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED }; //Mac address of the Arduino board
EthernetClient client;

void setup(){
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to obtaining an IP address using DHCP");
    while(true);
  }

  //Sending request to server
  char ServerAddress[] = "domain.name.com";
  if(client.connect(ServerAddress, 80)) {
    
    client.println("GET /file.php?data=10 HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + String(ServerAddress));
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println(); // end HTTP header
    
    client.stop();
  } else {// if not connected:
    Serial.println("Server connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

Basically I initialised the Ethernet Shield by only declaring the **MAC address**.

Then I connected the board to a **router**, so that during the initalisation the router's **DHCP** would automatically assing an IP address to the Ethernet Shield.
In this way everything starts correctly and I'm able to send GET requests to remote servers.